# RabbitMQ only allows one server in the "cluster"

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing

At the moment I'm exploring the possibilities of RabbitMQ. I'm trying to cluster 3 RabbitMQ servers on Virtual Machines (ubuntu14.04), connected to eachother in a LAN.

I succesfully clustered 2 RabbitMQ servers. (So my .erlang.cookie is correct, /etc/hosts is correct, machines can ping eachother, ...)

The configuration file of the servers is identical.

I find it strange that when I try to connect the 3rd RabbitMQ server to the cluster, it keeps failing until I stop the rabbitmq-server application on a (already) clustered server.

When trying to add the 3rd server I get the following error in the log files:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 16-Apr-2015::00:45:43 ===
Mnesia(rabbit@auser): ** ERROR ** Mnesia on rabbit@auser could not connect to node(s) [rabbit@virtual]
```

rabbit@virtual is the 2nd server added to the cluster. So it looks like I can only build a bridge instead of a cluster. I tested the current bridge connection and it is working perfect. What am I doing wrong?

The configuration file of the RabbitMQ servers is the following:

```
[{rabbit,        [{tcp_listeners,    [5672]}]},
 {rabbitmq_mqtt, [{default_user,     <<"guest">>},
              {default_pass,     <<"guest">>},
              {allow_anonymous,  true},
              {vhost,            <<"/">>},
              {exchange,         <<"MQTT">>},
              {subscription_ttl, 1800000},
              {prefetch,         10},
              {ssl_listeners,    []},
              %% Default MQTT with TLS port is 8883
              %% {ssl_listeners,    [8883]}
              {tcp_listeners,    [1883]},
              {tcp_listen_options, [binary,
                                    {packet,    raw},
                                    {reuseaddr, true},
                                    {backlog,   128},
                                    {nodelay,   true}]}]}
].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that you should not clone machines and just change the hostname. If you want to build a RabbitMQ cluster use 3 pure independent machines.